# Determine whether or not T is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4,$ with $T([x, y, z]) = [x + y + z, z − y, x − y, x + 1].$ I want to determine whether or not $T$ is a linear transformation.

I've tried to figure out how to approach this problem but cannot seem to get my head around it.
I'm not really sure how to check the addition and multiplication conditions for this question to prove whether this is a linear transformation or not.

If anybody could help me I would be very appreciative

Comment: Is $T(0,0,0)=(0,0,0,0)$?

Comment: Thats the format yeh

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. I'm giving you a hint.

Comment: Oh! I totally did, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disprove linearity, all you need is two points $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3,$ where $T(x + y) \neq T(x) + T(y)$

Try $x=(0,0,0)$ and $y=(1,1,1).$    Compute $T(x),$ $T(y)$ and $T(x+y)$ separately.